# How do I link (as an anchor link) to another answer on the same page?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Example: If I want to answer some question, and I want to link to another answer.

I can link normally like:

```
as Tsvetomir Tsonev's [answer][1]*

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/178450/622813
```

But this link will reload as a normal link.

Why can't I do a link like an anchor?

```
as Tsvetomir Tsonev's [answer][1]*

[1]: #178450
```